# How to select number of rows in the table

Tags: selenium

How can I select number of rows in the table from the following HTML on the page (NOTE: THERE ARE MULTIPLE TABLES IN THE PAGE). I have tried woth the script below, but it shows "Number of rows in this table = 0". Thanks for the help.

HTML:

```
    <table summary="" style="margin-top: 0px;">
        <thead>
          <tr>
           <th id="yui-dt0-th-name" rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">Advertiser
           </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

     <tbody class="yui-dt-message" style="display: none;">
        <tr class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">
          <td colspan="1" class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">
            <div class="yui-dt-liner yui-dt-loading">Loading...</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>

     <tbody tabindex="0" class="yui-dt-data" style="">
         <tr style="" id="yui-rec0" class="yui-dt-first yui-dt-even">
             <td headers="yui-dt0-th-name " class="yui-dt0-col-name yui-dt-col-name yui-dt-asc yui-dt-sortable yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">
                <div class="yui-dt-liner">FirstName</div>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="" id="yui-rec1" class="yui-dt-odd">
           <td headers="yui-dt0-th-name " class="yui-dt0-col-name yui-dt-col-name yui-dt-asc yui-dt-sortable yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">
              <div class="yui-dt-liner">SecondName</div>
           </td>
        </tr>

        <tr style="" id="yui-rec2" class="yui-dt-even">
            <td headers="yui-dt0-th-name " class="yui-dt0-col-name yui-dt-col-name yui-dt-asc yui-dt-sortable yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">
              <div class="yui-dt-liner">ThirdName</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

       <tr style="" id="yui-rec3" class="yui-dt-odd">
            <td headers="yui-dt0-th-name " class="yui-dt0-col-name yui-dt-col-name yui-dt-asc yui-dt-sortable yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">
                <div class="yui-dt-liner">FourthName</div>
            </td>
       </tr>

       <tr style="" id="yui-rec4" class="yui-dt-last yui-dt-even">
           <td headers="yui-dt0-th-name " class="yui-dt0-col-name yui-dt-col-name yui-dt-asc yui-dt-sortable yui-dt-first yui-dt-last">
                <div class="yui-dt-liner">FifthName</div>
           </td>
       </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My Script:

```
        WebElement table_element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("tbody"));     
        List<WebElement> tr_collection=table_element.findElements(By.className("yui-dt-data"));
        System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = " +tr_collection.size());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code to get the number of rows in the table (**including the column headers**):

```
List<WebElement> table_rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@summary='']//tr"));
System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+table_rows.size());
```

**NOTE: Assuming there is just one table in your webpage**

---

### Edit

It will **wait 10 seconds** to locate all the **`"tr"` tag elements of the `'table'` that has a `'td' tag` with exact innerHTML/text as 'FirstName'.**

```
try{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); //waiting for 10 seconds so the table is visible
    List<WebElement> table_rows= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[.='FirstName']/ancestor::table//tr")));
    System.out.println("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = "+table_rows.size());
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.err.println("Error while getting the table. "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: there are more tables

Comment: Does every table's tag read **`<table summary="" style="margin-top: 0px;">`** ? Or the attributes are different for each ?

Comment: @familyGuy: I have updated my code above under **Edit**. Please check and let me know if it works for you. Also, is the `"FirstName"` text unique in the webpage; means no other div tag is there with innerHTML/text as 'FirstName' ?

Comment: yes the name is unique, however, it still shows number of rows = 0

Comment: **I am getting output as '7' per your HTML code snippet**. Do one thing please. Add an implit wait time of "20 seconds" at the top using the code **`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`**. That way, sufficient time will be there for the table to load. If it still doesn't work, then [upload the image in imgur](http://imgur.com/) and add the link here related to the table in your webpage.

Comment: here is link to the image you asked for. Once again, I sincerely appreciate all of your help. :)        http://imgur.com/O2oImQh

Comment: Now I get it. **`The table is inside a popup, which took some time to come up. And, hence it was returning value as '0'`**. I have updated my code accordingly under **Edit**. Please check and let me know if it works out for you. Thanks.

Comment: now i am getting timed out error. But test case is not failing either. This is the error ---- Error while getting the table. Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.xpath: //div[.='myadv']/ancestor::table//tr

Comment: Is there an exact text **`myadv`** in the table ? Fyi, the text is also case-sensitive for the xpath. So, you need to take care of two things; There must be an exact text present in your table and the case must also match. Also, from what I remember, there was a text **My Advertisement**. So your xpath will be **`//div[.='My Advertisement']/ancestor::table//tr`**. Please edit accordingly and check.

Comment: Please let me know, if it worked out for you. Thanks :)

Comment: I am being very careful when adding text, but its giving me timed out error :(

Comment: Finally, Looks like we got it. So, I used FirePath in FF to get xpath of the table, which in return gave me number of rows 5.  This is the xpath I am using now: ".//*[@id='basic']/div[4]/table/tbody[2]/tr".   I understand that we are not supposed to say Thanks here, but I must say Thanks Much for all of your help. It was your efforts that made this case possible. Keep up the good work!!!!! :)

Comment: Glad that it worked out finally for you.. Cheers.. :)